# Domino 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack1 - how to update extension library on server?

Tags: xpages

I just installed the Upgrade Pack 1 on my Domino 8.5.3 server. How is the Extension Library updated now?  Documentation here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_the_upgrade_pack_on_a_Domino_server_ddxl853 says that I should remove OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=updateSite1.nsf from notes.ini so it means this update method is not beeing used anymore? How to update extlib instead? On Notes client I have used the File -> Application -> Install to update libraries but not sure how to do it on my server now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade Pack 1 contains the IBM supported version of the Extension Library from OpenNTF. As stated by Frantisek you should not mix UP1 and Extension Library from OpenNTF (unless you really know what you are doing and in this case you should only mix UP1 and the experimental part of the 853-20111215 release of Extension Library since that release matches UP1).

So (as stated in the documentation you link to) you need to remove Extension Library before installing UP1.

You need to install UP1 on the Notes clients too. This includes removing Extension Library from the clients too. See the documentation for more information: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_the_upgrade_pack_on_Domino_Designer_and_Notes_ddxl853

Alternatively you can choose to continue using the Extension Library from OpenNTF (and not install UP1). You just need to be aware that it is not supported by IBM.

Answer (score 3):

You should not mix Upgrade pack and Extension library, as stated here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_and_administering_the_XPages_Extension_Library_ddxl853